# My boxplot draws but the coordinates are NaN when I try to label the plot

Tags: pgfplots, labels, bar-chart, boxplot

I have been slowly getting my barchart with a boxplot to come together. My current project is to label the whiskers, quartiles and median. Using examples from the manual, no label is printed. This is a snippet of what I have:

```
\addplot[ boxplot={draw position=\numberofrows} ]
table[ y index=0, col sep=comma] {data.csv};
[above]
node[left] at (boxplot box cs: \boxplotvalue{lower whisker},1) {\pgfmathprintnumber{\boxplotvalue{lower whisker}}};
node[left] at (boxplot box cs: \boxplotvalue{lower quartile},1){\pgfmathprintnumber{\boxplotvalue{lower quartile}}}
node[left] at (boxplot box cs: \boxplotvalue{median},1)        {\pgfmathprintnumber{\boxplotvalue{median}}}
node[right]at (boxplot box cs: \boxplotvalue{average},1)       {\pgfmathprintnumber{\boxplotvalue{average}}}
node       at (boxplot box cs: \boxplotvalue{upper quartile},1){\pgfmathprintnumber{\boxplotvalue{upper quartile}}}
node[right]at (boxplot box cs: \boxplotvalue{upper whisker},1) {\pgfmathprintnumber{\boxplotvalue{upper whisker}}};

\draw  node[anchor=center,on top] at (axis cs:40.0,\numberofrows) {\pgfmathprintnumber{\boxplotvalue{median}}};
```

The `\pgfmathprintnumber{\boxplotvalue{median}}` prints `NaN` and that explains why the boxplot label values do not print. How does `\boxplotvalue{}` work? I'm using the code straight from the manual. Is the barchart causing problems with the boxplot coordinates? The boxplot draws with no labels. What do I need for something that seems so straight forward. Regards, Dave

Comment: Without a sample of `data.csv` it's impossible to say.